# How do i return the response of a fetch as a return type of a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I had a function in node.js from which i am making a fetch request to a url and obtaining response data from fetch and i would like to use this response data as a return type of the function.

Can anyone please help me with how to do this ? I am very new to node.js and this entire promise thing. Please Help me out

```
app.intent('get train number',(conv,{number})=>{
var result;
let data = fetch("https://myapp.herokuapp.com/status/number/yesterday")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(jsondata=> {
  result = jsondata.data;
  console.log(result); //this prints the required result well
});
return conv.close('The status of train number'+number+'is'+result);
});
```

I wanted to do this. Please do not down rate this question (or) if my question does not make sense. Instead let me know where i am wrong

Entire Code :-

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = dialogflow({debug:true});
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv)=>{
    conv.ask('Hello world!!');
});
app.intent('get train number',(conv,{number})=>{
var result = number;
let data = fetch("https://myapp.herokuapp.com/status/02723/yesterday")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(jsondata=> {
  result = jsondata.data;
  console.log(result);
});
return conv.close('The status of train number'+number+'is'+result);
});

const expressApp = express().use(bodyParser.json());
expressApp.post('/webhook',app);

expressApp.listen(port);
```

I am using Node.js

Comment: You need to call `conv.close` inside the `then` handler that has the `jsondata.data` payload, you **cannot** return things from a `Promise` the way you're thinking - asynchronous calls don't work like that.

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks for the suggestion. I understood that we can access that result in call backs but what i wanted is to return that result from the app.intent function in my code and i am not understanding how to do that

Comment: @desusaivenkat if that's the case, then `app.intent`'s callback must support asynchronous calls or have the ability to pass a `Promise` as the second argument. It would be useful to know what `app.intent` actually is.

Comment: @goto1 Actually i am writing a webhook for a dialog flow agent and app.intent('get train number') gets called when some one triggers a get train number intent in my dialog flow agent

Comment: This still doesn't help me understand what `app.intent` supports and what doesn't. Where is `app.intent` coming from? What framework/library/whatever are you using?

Comment: @goto1 I had updated the question with the entire code and required details now, please check that now. Hope it helps you now

Comment: @desusaivenkat yeah I am looking at the docs, you don't need to return anything - just call `conv.close` inside `then` after `console.log(result)`

Comment: @goto1 Thankyou mate, i will check that and let you know if that works around

Comment: *"i would like to use this response data as a return type of the function"*: that is like ordering a pizza online, clicking the order button, and expecting the pizza to be on your plate once you have clicked it. A function *cannot* return the asynchronous response *now* that will only be there in some *future*.

Answer (score 0):

You  can try this one, put return inside then:

```
app.intent('get train number',(conv,{number})=>{
    var result;
    let data = fetch("https://myapp.herokuapp.com/status/number/yesterday")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsondata=> {
    result = jsondata.data;
    console.log(result); //this prints the required result well
    return conv.close('The status of train number'+number+'is'+result);
    });
    });
```

Comment: The `return` statement does nothing in this case.